# Calling a function that does a jest.mock component doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to add a helper function to mock a component for all my tests.

I added this in setupTests.js:

```
export const mockMyComponent = () => {
  jest.mock('./MyComponent', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: ({ children }) => <>{children}</>,
  }));
};
```

If I call this function inside my test, my tests don't pass. However if I use jest.mock inside my test all my tests pass.

```
import ...

mockMyComponent(); // DOESNT WORK

/*
THIS WORKS

jest.mock('./MyComponent', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: ({ children }) => <>{children}</>,
}));
*/

describe('test', () => {
   test('mytest', () => { ... });
});
```

Comment: You need to mock at the top level so that the module is replaced when it's imported by the consumer (which is presumably what you're testing). If you don't, you need to explicitly reload all of the modules and import the consumer again. jest.mock calls get _hoisted_, calling your custom function doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know how can I :
```you need to explicitly reload all of the modules and import the consumer again```
Or do you know where can i find documentation about that? Can't find any in jest website

Comment: See e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules.

Comment: I think I didn't totally understand your answer.
It is possible to call jest.mock inside a custom function ?
I don't understand where I should call jest.resetModules